# Passing an array from model to table view within UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a simple app that:

- Returns data from a server on load
- Contains a `UITabBarController` with 2 items `ViewController` and `TableViewController`. The view is the first tab a user sees.

I have a model I am creating with data by calling this:

```
self.tide = [[TideModel alloc] initWithJSON:userLocationAsString];
```

I pass a longitude and latitude and it returns json. I have my view then accessing that data and displaying on the screen with no issues. What I am trying to solve now is how to get that data passed on to my `TableViewController` ?

**TableViewController.m**: (returns `null`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tide = [[TideModel alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.tide.tideSummary);
}
```

**TableViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) TideModel *tide;
```

**Few things**

- I am initializing my model with `initWithJSON`
- When a user views the tableview the model is already populated with data, so I dont need to resend the JSON (that would be over kill).
- Would a segue be needed if I am using data from a single model

---

**initWithJSON: below:**

```
    -(id)initWithJSON:(NSString *)location {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        NSString *locationQueryURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://x/location/%@", location];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager GET:locationQueryURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

           // Extra code cut out to save space
           ..................
           ..................
           ..................

            self.maxheight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dctOfTideSummaryStats valueForKey: @"maxheight"]];
            self.tideSummary = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"tide.tideSummary"];

    return self;
    }
```

---

**What is the best way to use that same data created and initialized from `initWithJSON` to be used within my TableViewController?** 
Thoughts?

Comment: if NSLog(@"%@", self.tide.tideSummary) is printing proper data then in viewDidLoad method then u can simply put that data in ur TableView. I think u should not get any problem to do that!!

Comment: It returns ```(null)``` - I will update my question

Comment: @NSS I looked in to a segue, but im not sending via an outlet. To be sure a segue is out of the question correct? Maybe if I was going from tableview -> detailview (without a tab bar)

Comment: @NSS Would i make a singleton object for my tideSummary?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't pass data between two different view controllers in a tab bar controller. They're siblings so they shouldn't need to be tightly coupled to each other.

When you get the data from the server I would persist it somewhere like Core Data.

Then you could pass the `NSManagedObjectContext` to each view controller and they can access the data from Core Data individually. In a standard view controller you could use a `NSFetchRequest` to retrieve the data. In the table view controller you could use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to access the data.

If you use Core Data I would recommend looking at the Master-Detail Xcode project template. Make sure to select 'Use Core Data'. To get started look at the Core Data Programming Guide and the Core Data related sample code on Apple's developer site. Marcus Zarra's [Core Data book](http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data) is also excellent and there's good info on Core Data Libraries and Utilities [here](http://nshipster.com/core-data-libraries-and-utilities/).

There are alternatives to Core Data as well. You could read/write to a plist file, you could use [`NSKeyedArchiver`](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/). There are also [frameworks](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle) to make working with models easier. There are a number of discussions available to help decide which persistence approach to choose.

But with any of these choices I would recommend accessing the model data individually from each VC and not passing it between them because they're siblings. If you have a parent/child VC setup like if you wanted to edit a value in a table view then it would be correct pass the model object from the parent to the child.

Comment: So that would be the best way to do so? Why couldnt I access my model? My view controller accesses it, so couldnt my table view?

Comment: It looks like your model is being created and loaded with data in the 1st VC. But this statement in your TVC [[TideModel alloc] init] will just create an new empty model object, different from the one in the 1st VC. So ideally you'll have a common place to persist your model to and then you can access it from any of your VCs.

Comment: Thanks for that. Eventually, ill have a table view with a search -> tap -> view the detail view (which I have now). I just return based on user location (starting skinny). The data is related to both tabs though in my case. Is there another way to create my model object and have data accessed throughout without CoreData? I feel it may be overkill when I want to access an array created when i init my model

Comment: Yes, you can use some of the other methods I listed. 1) You can write/read an array to NSUserDefaults. You can see how I persist data using NSUserDefaults and a singleton in this sample: https://github.com/soleares/SOLPresentingFun. Look in SOLOptions.m and SOLAppDelegate.m. 2) You can create a model object and serialize/deserialize it with NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver as long as it conforms to NSCoder. You may want to use Mantle to make this easier and reference the NSHipster article too. Links to both are in the answer. 3) If you need something more then use Core Data.